# How to query the percentage of data already cached when streaming video using GStreamer

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm just starting up with GStreamer and I am developing a simple Android application using GStreamer 1.5 that stream video over HTTP protocol. I want to implement function just similar to MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener so that I can show on the seek bar the percentage of data already cached from network as the secondary progress. Just as the behavior of the other video streaming application.
So, is there any way I can query that percentage?